# How to get the data from MYSQL database for a particular date where there is no record

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database where data is stored for particular users.The database also records the date and time when the user has inserted the data. I want to query and check if the user has not inserted any data for the previous dates. i.e. I want to know if the user has not inserted any data on a particular date and get that date for which no data has been inserted.Is it possible to get the date in that manner? I am trying the below query but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT date from employee_details where date < NOW() && date IS NULL;
```

Comment: You want `||` (`OR`), not `AND` (`&&`).

Comment: @Filburt I tried using OR(||). That won't return anything. I mean no data will be returned if I use OR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no data exists in employee_details for the give date (i.e. the user has done nothing on the given date) your query will not return anything.

You may create a separate table containing nothing but dates and use this to do an outer join to determine if no user data exists for the give day.

Comment: I tried doing that as you mentioned.I have created a table which contains the start_date for each user.And I am using this date in my employee_details table to check the get the dates between the start_date and current date to check if there is no data in any date between these two dates. I am using this query :  SELECT details.date FROM employee_details details LEFT JOIN employee_data data ON (data.name = details.name) WHERE details.date is null AND details.date BETWEEN data.start_date AND CURRENT_DATE() and details.name = "merk";     But this doesnot work.Can you please check?

Comment: You will not be able to find data (dates in your case) which is not stored in the database, unless you use some stored method trickery. 
If you are determined to solve this using sql - which I think is a questionable idea - you can create a separate table and fill it with all dates which your users may log activity on - literally all of them, in the past and in the future (for the latter i guess you can keep adding data every day). Then do an outer join to find which dates are missing in the activity log table.

Answer (score 0):

You are literally looking for a date that is before this date **AND** the date has not been filled in, so that code won't work. You probable want to replace the `date IS NULL` to `empty_data_column IS NULL` if that is what you want

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
select *  FROM employee_details WHERE date <= CURDATE() OR date is null;
```

This means:

```
select *
```

(select everything)

```
from employee_details
```

(from table_name)

```
where date <= CURDATE() OR date is null;
```

(date is less or the same as the actual date ***OR*** the date is null)

**Note:**

1. in case you want **both conditions at the same time**, ***substitute or with and***.
2. **CURDATE()** returns the DATE part of the current time. [Manual on CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)
3. **NOW()** returns the date and time portions as a timestamp in various formats, depending on how it was requested. [Manual on
       NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

Comment: in case you want both conditions at the same time, substitute or with and. 

select *  FROM employee_details WHERE date <= CURDATE() AND date is null;

Comment: Code only answers are considered bad practice please explain your code.